# How much maximum money can transfer on regular base from USA to India?

Tags: united-states, india, international-transfer, wire-transfer

I have 3 questions to avoid IRS penalty-

1. I am on employment based visa in USA and want to send dollars from USA to India from my savings (after paying Tax). How much maximum dollars I can send in a day? month? or in a year regularly?
2. To pay the Bank Loan-student Loan how much maximum dollars I can send in a day, in a month or in a year? to pay that I have to pay directly to that Bank Account or in any account I can send money?
3. My mother is having Green Card. She is not working. She has a NRE account in India. Can I send dollars from my USA Bank account to her NRE account in India? what are the rules for that? any Tax or limit for that? Or I have to get any permission before sending it?

Even Bankers have no answers for these questions. Please guide me properly.

Comment: What IRS penalty are you talking about?

Comment: Is your mother in US and is she a Non-Resident Indian for tax purposes?

Comment: Yes, my mother is in the US and NRI.

Comment: I am talking about the inquiry of IRS. I have read some where that if a person send $10,000 or more than that he has to face IRS inquiry. so I want to know the limit and rules.

Comment: @Amin There is no such thing. The IRS doesn't care until you die, at which point your estate owes tax on any amount over ~$5 million transferred.

Comment: @Amin, what you mention about the $10k limit is actually related to filing [FBAR](https://www.irs.gov/businesses/small-businesses-self-employed/report-of-foreign-bank-and-financial-accounts-fbar). Any US resident (from IRS definition) who has a balance of more than $10k in any foreign accounts (cash or non-cash) at any point in a year needs to file FBAR with the treasury department. For more info, you can also see [this link](http://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/irs-reporting-rules-foreign-bank-accounts-fbar.html).

Answer (score 1):

> I am on employment based visa in USA and want to send dollars from USA to India from my savings (after paying Tax). How much maximum dollars I can send in a day? month? or in a year regularly?

There is no such limit. You can transfer as money you like to yourself anywhere.

> To pay the Bank Loan-student Loan how much maximum dollars I can send in a day, in a month or in a year? to pay that I have to pay directly to that Bank Account or in any account I can send money?

You can transfer to your NRE account in India and move it further. You can also send it directly to the Loan Account [Check with the Bank, they may not be able to receive funds from outside for a Loan Account]

> My mother is having Green Card. She is not working. She has a NRE account in India. Can I send dollars from my USA Bank account to her NRE account in India? what are the rules for that? any Tax or limit for that? Or I have to get any permission before sending it?

If you are sending money to your mother, it would come under Gift Tax act in US. There is no issue in India. Suggest you transfer to your own NRE account.